# i am trying to create a web page that will display the audit details of users but nothing is displayed on execution

Tags: c#

This code is running without errors but it is not displaying any output.  The data to be displayed is:

- recordid
- operation details
- login id
- from ip
- operation performed date and time
- from page url referrer
- user agent

The code I have written is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.ComponentModel;



public partial class Auditlog : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)


    {
    }
    //returns audit-log detail
    public static DataTable GetLogEntries(long RecordId)
    {


        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = null;

        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AgentTrackingConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [AuditLog] WHERE RecordID=@RecordID";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@RecordID",
                DbType = DbType.Int64,
                Value = RecordId
            });

            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log exception here
            //rethrow so that ui-layer also throw it and show a custom error page
            //to visitor.
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        //return the datatable containing result rows.
        return dt;
    }


    //returns audit-log for displaying.
    public static DataTable GetLogEntries()
    {


        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = null;

        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AgentTrackingConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [AuditLog] ORDER BY RecordID DESC";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log exception here
            //rethrow so that ui-layer also throw it and show a custom error page
            //to visitor.
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        //return the datatable containing result rows.
        return dt;
    }

    //adds new entry to audit-log

    public static void LogEntry(string OperationDetails)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        int result = 0;

        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AgentTrackingConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [AuditLog]([OperationDetails],[OperationPerformedDateTime],[LoginId],[FromPage],[FromIP],[UrlReferrer],[UserAgent]) VALUES(@OperationDetails,@OperationPerformedDateTime,@LoginId,@FromPage,@FromIP,@UrlReferrer,@UserAgent)";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            string _OperationDetails = OperationDetails.Replace("'", " ").Replace("-", " ");
            string _LoginId = null;
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["LoginId"] != null)
            {
                _LoginId = HttpContext.Current.Session["LoginId"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                _LoginId = "N.A";
            }

                string _FromPage = null;
                // string MyEncoder = null;
                if (HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl != null)
                {
                    _FromPage = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode((HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl.Replace("'", " ").Replace("-", " ")));
                }
                else
                {
                    _FromPage = "N.A";
                }
                string _FromIP = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode((string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]) ? HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"] : HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]).ToString().Replace("'", " ").Replace("-", " "));
                string _UrlReferrer = null;
                if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer != null)
                {
                    _UrlReferrer = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString().Replace("'", " ").Replace("-", " "));
                }
                else
                {
                    _UrlReferrer = "N.A";
                }
                string _UserAgent = null;
                if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent != null)
                {
                    _UserAgent = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent.Replace("'", " ").Replace("-", " "));
                }
                else
                {
                    _UserAgent = "N.A";
                }


            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@OperationDetails",
                DbType = DbType.String,
                Value = _OperationDetails
            });
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@OperationPerformedDateTime",
                DbType = DbType.DateTime,
                Value = DateTime.Now
            });
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@LoginId",
                DbType = DbType.String,
                Size = 50,
                Value = _LoginId
            });
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@FromPage",
                DbType = DbType.String,
                Value = _FromPage
            });
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@FromIP",
                DbType = DbType.String,
                Size = 50,
                Value = _FromIP
            });
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@UrlReferrer",
                DbType = DbType.String,
                Size = 100,
                Value = _UrlReferrer
            });
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@UserAgent",
                DbType = DbType.String,
                Value = _UserAgent
            });



            con.Open();
            result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log exception here
            //rethrow so that ui-layer also throw it and show a custom error page
            //to visitor.
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }

    }


    public static void LogEntry(string OperationDetails, string LoginId)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        int result = 0;

        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AgentTrackingConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [AuditLog]([OperationDetails],[OperationPerformedDateTime],[LoginId],[FromPage],[FromIP],[UrlReferrer],[UserAgent]) VALUES(@OperationDetails,@OperationPerformedDateTime,@LoginId,@FromPage,@FromIP,@UrlReferrer,@UserAgent)";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            string _OperationDetails = OperationDetails.Replace("'", " ").Replace("-", " ");
            string _LoginId = null;
            if (LoginId != null)
            {
                _LoginId = LoginId;
            }
            else
            {
                _LoginId = "N.A";
            }
            string _FromPage = null;
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl != null)
            {
                _FromPage = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl.Replace("'", " ").Replace("-", " "));
            }
            else
            {
                _FromPage = "N.A";
            }
            string _FromIP = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode((string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]) ? HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"] : HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]).ToString().Replace("'", " ").Replace("-", " "));
            string _UrlReferrer = null;
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer != null)
            {
                _UrlReferrer = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString().Replace("'", " ").Replace("-", " "));
            }
            else
            {
                _UrlReferrer = "N.A";
            }
            string _UserAgent = null;
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent != null)
            {
                _UserAgent = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent.Replace("'", " ").Replace("-", " "));
            }
            else
            {
                _UserAgent = "N.A";
            }
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@OperationDetails",
                DbType = DbType.String,
                Value = _OperationDetails
            });
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@OperationPerformedDateTime",
                DbType = DbType.DateTime,
                Value = DateTime.Now
            });
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@LoginId",
                DbType = DbType.String,
                Size = 50,
                Value = _LoginId
            });
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@FromPage",
                DbType = DbType.String,
                Value = _FromPage
            });
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@FromIP",
                DbType = DbType.String,
                Size = 50,
                Value = _FromIP
            });
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@UrlReferrer",
                DbType = DbType.String,
                Size = 100,
                Value = _UrlReferrer
            });
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@UserAgent",
                DbType = DbType.String,
                Value = _UserAgent
            });



            con.Open();
            result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log exception here
            //rethrow so that ui-layer also throw it and show a custom error page
            //to visitor.
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }

    }


    public static void LogEntry(string OperationDetails, string LoginId, string RawUrl, string IpAddress, string UrlReferrer, string UserAgent)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        int result = 0;

        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AgentTrackingConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [AuditLog]([OperationDetails],[OperationPerformedDateTime],[LoginId],[FromPage],[FromIP],[UrlReferrer],[UserAgent]) VALUES(@OperationDetails,@OperationPerformedDateTime,@LoginId,@FromPage,@FromIP,@UrlReferrer,@UserAgent)";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            string _OperationDetails = OperationDetails.Replace("'", " ").Replace("-", " ");
            string _LoginId = null;
            if (LoginId != null)
            {
                _LoginId = LoginId;
            }
            else
            {
                _LoginId = "N.A";
            }
            string _FromPage = null;
            if (RawUrl != null)
            {
                _FromPage = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(RawUrl.Replace("'", " ").Replace("-", " "));
            }
            else
            {
                _FromPage = "N.A";
            }
            string _FromIP = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(IpAddress);
            string _UrlReferrer = null;
            if (UrlReferrer != null)
            {
                _UrlReferrer = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(UrlReferrer.ToString().Replace("'", " ").Replace("-", " "));
            }
            else
            {
                _UrlReferrer = "N.A";
            }
            string _UserAgent = null;
            if (UserAgent != null)
            {
                _UserAgent = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(UserAgent.Replace("'", " ").Replace("-", " "));
            }
            else
            {
                _UserAgent = "N.A";
            }

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@OperationDetails",
                DbType = DbType.String,
                Value = _OperationDetails
            });
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@OperationPerformedDateTime",
                DbType = DbType.DateTime,
                Value = DateTime.Now
            });
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@LoginId",
                DbType = DbType.String,
                Size = 50,
                Value = _LoginId
            });
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@FromPage",
                DbType = DbType.String,
                Value = _FromPage
            });
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@FromIP",
                DbType = DbType.String,
                Size = 50,
                Value = _FromIP
            });
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@UrlReferrer",
                DbType = DbType.String,
                Size = 100,
                Value = _UrlReferrer
            });
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@UserAgent",
                DbType = DbType.String,
                Value = _UserAgent
            });





            con.Open();
            result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log exception here
            //rethrow so that ui-layer also throw it and show a custom error page
            //to visitor.
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }

    }

    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}





    enter code here
```

Comment: You have added all of your code. Can you describe the problem in more detail and tell us what you've tried to find the problem. Have you used the debugger? Show the relevant part of the code not all.

Comment: Well, there is one thing obvious: you haven't used any of those methods in `Page_Load`.

Comment: problem is tat when i am debugging the code it is giving no errors bt its not displaying the data also tat is to be displayed...i posted the whole code bcz i was thinking weather my code is wrong or any other issue is there.

Comment: But why do you think that anything should be shown if you don't call these methods? Maybe your aspx contains code that calls them but then you haven't shown it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter i absolutely agree with you, there is no method in `Page_Load` `Event`

Comment: @sanya you have to call these methods somewhere, right now you are doing logical mistake, first execute these methods and see what results it gives you

Comment: i called the method in page load now and its giving error now as: System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
  Source=App_Web_hzk3her3
  StackTrace:
     System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
  Source=App_Web_hzk3her3
  StackTrace:
       at Auditlog.GetLogEntries() in c:\Users\dell 1\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\WebSitecountry\Auditlog.aspx.cs:line 108